Limiting minting supply of fungible token
I'm trying to understand how to limit max_supply of Mint token (using fungible SPL Token).
In example (from this repo):
    pub fn create_token(ctx: Context<CreateToken>, decimals: u8, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        system_program::create_account(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                system_program::CreateAccount {
                    from: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.mint_token.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            10_000_000,
            82,
            ctx.accounts.token_program.key,
        )?;

        initialize_mint(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                InitializeMint {
                    mint: ctx.accounts.mint_token.to_account_info(),
                    rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            decimals,
            ctx.accounts.signer.key,
            Some(ctx.accounts.signer.key),
        )?;

        associated_token::create(CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.associate_token_program.to_account_info(),
            associated_token::Create {
                payer: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                associated_token: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint_token.to_account_info(),
                system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            },
        ))?;

        mint_to(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                MintTo {
                    authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                    mint: ctx.accounts.mint_token.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            amount,
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }

and this is CreateToken structure:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateToken<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint_token: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    ///CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub token_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associate_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

So i probably should use something like:
#[account(mut)]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

to get supply parameter, but how to init(get details of) this account in createToken method? IS there any method/example to it?

In SPL Token, tokens must exist in a token account, so there's no concept of max_supply. You'll either need to enforce the max supply in your minting logic, or pre-mint the max supply into some other token account, and then distribute tokens from that account.
For the first approach, that could look very similar to your example by changing the mint to pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>, as you point out. With that, you can do:
    const MAX_SUPPLY: u64 = 1_000_000_000; // example value
    pub fn create_token(ctx: Context<CreateToken>, decimals: u8, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        if ctx.accounts.mint.supply.saturating_add(amount) < MAX_SUPPLY {
            mint_to(
                CpiContext::new(
                    ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                    MintTo {
                        authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                        mint: ctx.accounts.mint_token.to_account_info(),
                        to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                    },
                ),
                amount,
            )?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }

You can find the Mint struct definition at https://github.com/solana-program/token/blob/62ff9d3ca0651b245ec281af68bd50302bff84b8/program/src/state.rs#L18
